# несколько *бип* в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли способы запустить несколько одновременных бип-каний в python. Я пытался использовать winsound.Beep и запустить в нескольких потоках, но увы, не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from win32api import Beep
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def do():
    for i in range(5):
        sleep(0.5)
        Beep(1046, 1000)

def mi():
    for i in range(5):
        sleep(0.3)
        Beep(1318, 300)

th_do5 = Thread(target=do)
th_mi5 = Thread(target=mi)
th_do5.start()
th_mi5.start()
```

Comment: А как запустить потоки одновременно?

Comment: Вообще потоки запускаются параллельно, скорее всего Beep не позволяет.

Comment: Поищите другую библиотеку.